# How to make `Cartogram` in Flutter

Tags: flutter, cartogram

I'm new to Flutter. I want to create a flutter app that show data on the map in the form of cartogram. I just want to render map from geojson file. Is it possible to do that? If it is possible, let me know how to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the solution here, so check this :   https://pub.dev/packages/geojson